# Electrical specifications for a microphone as good as human ear?

Tags: microphone

I need to buy a microphone to dectect sounds with at least the sensitivity of the human ear. It is for a Raspberry Pi that detects neighbours voices (late at night and loud conversations throughout the day) from 10 to 20m away. A speaker would play white noise to drown out their voices. I had a look at mic sensitivity (https://www.dpamicrophones.com/mic-university/how-to-read-microphone-specifications) but couldnt find how to choose a mic that is approx. as good as the human ear.

Comment: "As good as a human ear" isn't really an *engineering* specification.  And realistically, it's not something you need.  Your first problem is figuring out how to have the microphone not pick up your white noise too; maybe you put the noise machine inside and the microphone outside.  Realistically just give yourself a "gain" knob to turn and if you don't think the adaptive white noise is loud enough, turn the knob or tune the algorithm which varies the white noise based on the detected sound.

Comment: But you may not like having a burst of white noise every time someone over there cracks a particularly funny joke.  It may be better to set a constant level, or sleep with earplugs.

Comment: Also a huge part of the human hearing system is the very complex processing done by the brain, so even if your microphone is mechanically as good as the human ear, it still may not perform as well

Comment: Get a parabolic mic, a 2 s audio delay and play it back to them through a small speaker so they can just become aware of it. It should spook them out enough to talk more quietly.

Comment: A human has stereoscopic hearing and a brain to figure out lots of stuff so asking for a mic as good as the human ear is not a valid equality.

Comment: I think you're looking for a noise floor well below 10dB SPL, quite challenging.

Comment: Which human ear - they vary from good to deaf.

Comment: Chris: yes; the mic faces the window and the speaker faces my room. I'll be training an AI that will eventually figure out frequencies to ignore, which frequency spectrum or music is best for masking any particular neighbours voice. Am worried about prolonged sound affecting my ear though. @Transistor: I considered playing back their own voices but wont it be illegal and just cause them to retaliate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've tried until now, a USB microphone with sensitivity -67dBV/pBar, -47dBV/Pascal (these were mentioned on the back-cover of the microphone packaging) is good enough to just be able to detect human voices. It does get overrun with background noise, but as long as the noise is digitally eliminated and the sound is amplified, I believe it should be good enough to use and then convert to a Fourier Spectrum to be able to analyze the frequencies that need to be considered when playing back sound that can nullify the voices.

As per what I understand from [this page](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/understanding-microphone-sensitivity.html#), -30dBV/Pascal would be a mic of higher sensitivity than what I purchased. I'm not yet sure of what specification would be as good as a human ear because I couldn't yet try different microphones, but for starters, a cheaply available -47dBV/Pascal mic should suffice.

<del>testing strikeout text</del>

Comment: `<del>...<\del>`, I think.

Comment: @Transistor: That's right. `<del></del>` it is. Thank you. It's odd that the GUI does not provide the option anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most perfect microphone you can by for money, which of course outperforms the human ear by factors is a new invention by an Austrian physicist:

https://xarion.com/en/

but perhaps this 4500€ parabolic microphone I found in a german online spyshop is more practical

https://www.spyshop.berlin/parabolisches-richtmikrofon-g-pks-pro-pro-ex-831.html

but you will find easily a parabolic mic at amazon for less than 50€/$ (guess you can search yourself)
maybe you want to try one of these first :-) Looks more like toys, but worth a try

Comment: Thank you schnedan. The reason I asked on this forum was to know the electronics specifications when I search for a microphone. The impedance value, diaphragm, dBA value etc. which would give me a mic that is sensitive enough. The mic will be connected to a Raspberry Pi USB port, so I'm also asking friends and the Raspberry Pi forum, trying to learn to evaluate the current and wattage when selecting a mic.

Comment: so, what you want is frequency from 80 Hz bis 12 kHz according to Wikipedia, with 300 ... 3400 Hz as the Core (needed to understand whats spoken). Normal Voice you can assume 10-20dB loudness and ~6dB loss when distance is doubled. so for 20m you need to be already quite sensitive.